# Is intltoolize obsolete? If so, is there any alternatives?

Tags: linux, compiling, autotools

From [GNOME page](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeCommon/Migration), it states:

> If you are still using the almost obsolete `intltoolize`, then add the following line immediately before `autoreconf`:
>
> ```
> intltoolize --force --copy --automake || exit 1
> ```

Is `intltoolize` obsolete? If so, is there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

There is another GNOME page guide how to [Migrating from Intltool to Gettext](https://wiki.gnome.org/MigratingFromIntltoolToGettext). From that page, it states:

> Since about version 0.18, `Gettext` has been adding support for a lot more file formats that are used in modern GNOME desktop applications. This has slowly been making `Intltool` obsolete, which was invented to bridge that gap between what Gettext supported and what applications needed.

Answer (score 1):

Literally the first sentence on the page to which you link in your question answers it.

> `gnome-common` [which contains `intltoolize`] is completely deprecated, in favour of using macros from upstream [autoconf-archive](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/), and open-coding things in `autogen.sh`.